# Why is make appending '.o' to the end of my header file prerequisite?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to build a project with subdirectories using make, I've gotten the recursive make part working but for some reason, it seems to take the prerequisites of the source file dependencies and appends `.o` to them and then tries to compile them, which doesn't work obviously, why is it doing this?

The rule in question looks like this:

```
operations_cache.o : memory_management/operations_cache.cpp memory_management/operations_cache.hpp \
    function.hpp operations/operation_base.hpp
    cd memory_management && $(MAKE) $@
```

The rule that compiles the `operations` directory looks like this:

```
operation_%.o : function.hpp
    cd operations && $(MAKE) $@
```

for some reason, make keeps trying to say that `operations/operation_base.hpp.o` is a valid target even though I don't have it listed anywhere in the make file. I've read the documentation for and I didn't see anything in it about trying to implicitly define objects based on prerequisite filenames, so I'm super confused as to what is compelling it to do this.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++    -c -o node.o node.cpp
cd memory_management && make unique_table.o
make[1]: Entering directory './memory_management'
g++ -o ../unique_table.o -c unique_table.cpp
make[1]: Leaving directory './memory_management'
cd operations && make operations/operation_base.hpp.o
make[1]: Entering directory './operations'
g++ -o ../operations/operation_base.hpp.o -c 
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o' failed
make[1]: *** [operations/operation_base.hpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory './operations'
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o' failed
make: *** [operations/operation_base.hpp.o] Error 2
```

### Edit Added complete files

At user request, here are the complete make files of my 3 directories

./Makefile

```
CC = g++
objects = main.o node.o unique_table.o operations_cache.o function.o operation_base.o operation_and.o
# shared_lib = nodelib.so

all : edit # $(shared_lib)

edit : $(objects)
    $(CC) -o edit $(objects)

main.o : main.cpp node.hpp memory_management/unique_table.hpp memory_management/operations_cache.hpp

node.o : node.cpp node.hpp

unique_table.o : memory_management/unique_table.cpp memory_management/unique_table.hpp node.hpp
    cd memory_management && $(MAKE) $@

operations_cache.o : memory_management/operations_cache.cpp memory_management/operations_cache.hpp \
    function.hpp operations/operation_base.hpp
    cd memory_management && $(MAKE) $@

function.o : function.cpp function.hpp node.hpp memory_management/unique_table.hpp

operation_%.o : function.hpp
    cd operations && $(MAKE) $@

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm edit $(objects)
```

./operations/Makefile

```
CC = g++
objects = operation_base.o operation_and.o operation_or.o operation_xor.o operation_restrict.o operation_composition.o operation_satisfy.o operation_satisfy_all.o
proj_dir = ../

operation_base.o : operation_base.cpp operation_base.hpp $(proj_dir)function.hpp

operation_and.o : operation_and.cpp operation_and.hpp operation_base.hpp $(proj_dir)function.hpp

operation_or.o : operation_or.cpp operation_or.hpp operation_base.hpp $(proj_dir)function.hpp

operation_xor.o : operation_xor.cpp operation_xor.hpp operation_base.hpp $(proj_dir)function.hpp

operation_composition.o : operation_composition.cpp operation_composition.hpp operation_base.hpp $(proj_dir)function.hpp

operation_restrict.o : operation_restrict.cpp operation_restrict.hpp operation_base.hpp $(proj_dir)function.hpp

operation_satisfy.o : operation_satisfy.cpp operation_satisfy.hpp operation_base.hpp $(proj_dir)function.hpp

operation_satisfy_all.o : operation_satisfy_all.cpp operation_satisfy_all.hpp operation_satisfy.hpp

%.o : 
    $(CC) -o $(proj_dir)$@ -c $<
```

./memory_management/Makefile

```
CC = g++
objects = operations_cache.o unique_table.o
proj_dir = ../

operations_cache.o : operations_cache.cpp operations_cache.hpp \
    $(proj_dir)function.hpp $(proj_dir)operations/operation_base.hpp

unique_table.o : unique_table.cpp unique_table.hpp $(proj_dir)node.hpp

%.o : 
    $(CC) -o $(proj_dir)$@ -c $<
```

### Edit I found a solution

Removing `memory_management/operations_cache.cpp memory_management/operations_cache.hpp function.hpp operations/operation_base.hpp` from the `operations_cache.o` line solves the problem, it doesn't explain why the error was there, but it works, I'd still be interested in understanding why that happened though.

Comment: Looks like something out there went a little bit mad and tried to build a header file. I don't see it in the snippets provided, but my make-fu is weak at best. Someone more skilled might be able to answer off of what you've provided, but I recommend making am more complete example, just in case.

Comment: I went ahead and added the full file for now, I'll try and create an isolated test case in a bit

Comment: Cannot reproduce it here.

Comment: What purpose do you intend to serve with a pattern rule in which a '%' appears only in the target, not in any of its prerequisites?  That rule probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Correction: *those* rules probably don't mean what you think they mean, and independent of that, the ones in the subdirectory makefiles are positively broken.  It is one of the latter that is directly responsible for the compilation failure, though I'm still trying to sort out why it gets triggered at all for the indicated target.

Comment: I think of I added the % to the prereqs then it would recompile the operator classes any time any of the operators changed, and I only want them to recompile if one of *their* files change... If that makes sense. I've read the documentation on pattern matching, but I will admit I'm not Uber familiar with it yet, so I might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `operations/operation_base.hpp` happens to match `operation_%.o` rule and due to the fact of built-in rule:

```
.o:
#  Builtin rule
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

It works this way:

- check if `operations/operation_base.hpp` can be updated with an explicit rule (no),
- check all implicit (pattern) rules whether they can be resolved (candidate: built-in `%: %.o`),
- check if prerequisite `operations/operation_base.hpp.o` can be resolved (candidate: `operation_%.o: functions.hpp`),
- check if prerequisite `functions.hpp` can be resolved (yes, file exists),
- follow the rule `operation_%.o: functions.hpp` with stem `operations/base.hpp` (execute recipe that fails).

I have prepared a simplified `Makefile` that reproduces the issue. It requires that both `functions.hpp` exist and built-in rules are enabled.

```
all: operations/operation_base.hpp

operation_%.o: functions.hpp
        echo Making $@ from $<
```

Output:

```
# Only Makefile (no functions.hpp)
$ ls
Makefile
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'operations/operation_base.hpp', needed by 'all'.  Stop.

# Create functions.hpp to fulfill pattern rule (this is the case in question)
$ touch functions.hpp
$ make
echo Making operations/operation_base.hpp.o from functions.hpp
Making operations/operation_base.hpp.o from functions.hpp
# The following output comes from built-in rule %: %.o
cc   operations/operation_base.hpp.o   -o operations/operation_base.hpp
make: cc: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'operations/operation_base.hpp' failed

# The same, but with disabled built-in rules
$ make -r
make: *** No rule to make target 'operations/operation_base.hpp', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

Generally when you don't know why make decided to do something, it's useful to run it with `-d` to debug decision making and `-p` to get final resolved `Makefile`. It confirms the scenario:

```
$ make -d
…
 No implicit rule found for 'all'.
  Considering target file 'operations/operation_base.hpp'.
   File 'operations/operation_base.hpp' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'operations/operation_base.hpp'.
…
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'base.hpp'.
    Trying rule prerequisite 'functions.hpp'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'operations/operation_base.hpp'.
…
     No need to remake target 'functions.hpp'.
   Considering target file 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o'.
    File 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o' does not exist.
     Pruning file 'functions.hpp'.
    Finished prerequisites of target file 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o'.
   Must remake target 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o'.
echo Making operations/operation_base.hpp.o from functions.hpp
…
   Successfully remade target file 'operations/operation_base.hpp.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'operations/operation_base.hpp'.
  Must remake target 'operations/operation_base.hpp'.
cc   operations/operation_base.hpp.o   -o operations/operation_base.hpp
…
make: cc: Command not found
…
<builtin>: recipe for target 'operations/operation_base.hpp' failed
```

Fragments of resolved `Makefile` (`make -p`):

```
operations/operation_base.hpp: operations/operation_base.hpp.o
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'operations/operation_base.hpp'
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has been updated.
#  Failed to be updated.
# automatic
# @ := operations/operation_base.hpp
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * := operations/operation_base.hpp
# automatic
# + := operations/operation_base.hpp.o
# automatic
# | :=
# automatic
# < := operations/operation_base.hpp.o
# automatic
# ^ := operations/operation_base.hpp.o
# automatic
# ? := operations/operation_base.hpp.o
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/22=5%
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

operations/operation_base.hpp.o: functions.hpp
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'operations/base.hpp'
#  File is an intermediate prerequisite.
#  File does not exist.
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := operations/operation_base.hpp.o
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * := operations/base.hpp
# automatic
# + := functions.hpp
# automatic
# | :=
# automatic
# < := functions.hpp
# automatic
# ^ := functions.hpp
# automatic
# ? := functions.hpp
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/13=8%
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 4):
        echo Making $@ from $<
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! I did not know `-d` existed otherwise I would've used it.